# Creating a function to return results from a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a method, which works fine standalone, that I would like to turn into a function or SP. I have searched through lots of on-line questions and answers, but none have given me enough information to find out what is wrong.

The table itself does not need to be a variable as it is always the same, but the find type (@FindTypeID), quantity (@qtyfld) and weight (@wtfld) fields can be different.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReturnFindsWithNotes
    (@table nvarchar(50), @FindTypeID int, @qtyfld nvarchar(50), @wtfld nvarchar(50))
    RETURNS @query TABLE 
    (
        [SiteCodeID] int NULL,
        [TrenchID] int NULL, 
        [Context] [nvarchar](20),
        [FindsID] int NULL,
        [BagNo] [nvarchar](20),
        [FindTypeID] [int] NULL,
        [FindQty] [int] NULL,
        [FindWeight] [float] NULL,
        [FindNotes] [nvarchar](500) NULL
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT @query
        SELECT
            'SELECT * INTO #temp1
            FROM
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, ' + @FindTypeID + ' As FindTypeID, ' + @qtyfld + ' AS FindQty, ' + @wtfld + ' AS FindWeight, Notes, NotesToType
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM((b.splitdata))) AS FindNotes
            FROM ' + @table + 
            ' CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.Notes,''^'') AS b
            ) AS k

            SELECT * INTO #temp2
            FROM
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, ' + @FindTypeID + ' As FindTypeID, ' + @qtyfld + ' AS FindQty, ' + @wtfld + ' AS FindWeight, Notes, NotesToType
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM((c.splitdata))) As FindTypeIDFromNotes
            FROM ' + @table + 
            ' CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.NotesToType,''^'') AS c
            ) AS l
            INSERT INTO @query ([SiteCodeID], [TrenchID], [Context], [FindsID], [BagNo], [FindTypeID], [FindQty], [FindWeight], [FindNotes])
            SELECT #temp1.SiteCodeID, #temp1.TrenchID, #temp1.Context, #temp1.FindsID, #temp1.BagNo, #temp1.FindTypeID, #temp1.FindQty, #temp1.FindWeight, FindNotes
            FROM #temp1 JOIN #temp2 on #temp1.ID = #temp2.ID WHERE FindTypeIDFromNotes = ' + @FindTypeID + '
            DROP TABLE #temp1
            DROP TABLE #temp2'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table
        RETURN
    END
```

Above is where I got to, but when executing to create the function I get the error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReturnFindsWithNotes, Line 16
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

And I would assume the following to retrieve the data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ReturnFindsWithNotes ('FindsNWW', 12, 'PotWt', 'PotWt')
```

Very many thanks to @Spock. With some additional stuff I'd left outside, it now work. The following is what I have working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnFindsWithNotes
        @table          nvarchar(50), 
        @FindTypeID     int, 
        @qtyfld         nvarchar(50), 
        @wtfld          nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SQL = '
    CREATE TABLE #temp1(
    [SiteCodeID] int,
    [TrenchID] int,
    [Context] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [FindsID] int,
    [BagNo] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [FindTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FindQty] [int] NULL,
    [FindWeight] [float] NULL,
    [FindNotes] [nvarchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
)

select * into #temp2
from
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, 1 As FindTypeID, OtherQty, OtherWt, Notes, NotesToType
    ,ltrim(rtrim((b.splitdata))) AS Notes1
FROM FindsNWW
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.Notes,''^'') AS b
) AS k

select * into #temp3
from
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, 1 As FindTypeID, OtherQty, OtherWt, Notes, NotesToType
    ,ltrim(rtrim((c.splitdata))) As Notes2
FROM FindsNWW
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.NotesToType,''^'') AS c
) AS l
INSERT INTO [#temp1] ([SiteCodeID], [TrenchID], [Context], [FindsID], [BagNo], [FindTypeID], [FindQty], [FindWeight], [FindNotes])
select #temp2.SiteCodeID, #temp2.TrenchID, #temp2.Context, #temp2.FindsID, #temp2.BagNo, #temp2.FindTypeID,#temp2.OtherQty, #temp2.OtherWt, Notes1
from #temp2 join #temp3 on #temp2.ID = #temp3.ID Where Notes2 = 1
drop table #temp2
drop table #temp3

CREATE TABLE #temp4(
    [SiteCodeID] int NULL,
    [TrenchID] int NULL, 
    [Context] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FindsID] int NULL,
    [BagNo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FindTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FindQty] [int] NULL,
    [FindWeight] [float] NULL,
    [FindNotes] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #temp4 ([SiteCodeID], [TrenchID], [Context], [FindsID], [BagNo], [FindTypeID], [FindQty], [FindWeight], [FindNotes])
SELECT [SiteCodeID], [TrenchID], [Context], [FindsID], [BagNo], [FindTypeID], [FindQty], [FindWeight], 
CASE WHEN [FindNotes] = '''' THEN NULL ELSE [FindNotes] END
FROM [#temp1] ORDER BY SiteCodeID,[TrenchID], Context, [FindsID], BagNo, FindTypeID
DROP TABLE #temp1
SELECT * FROM #temp4 ORDER BY FindsID
DROP TABLE #temp4'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FindTypeID  INT', @FindTypeID

END
```

Comment: Too many mistakes are there to point out. First of all you cannot create `temp tables` inside function so make this a procedure

Comment: The error is because you are trying to insert into your table but you only have one column in your select statement, that big ugly dynamic sql string. This needs a complete rethinking of what you are trying to do. The temp tables make no sense here at all, a cte would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a UDF for this.
You'll need dynamic SQL to solve the problem.

UDFs have some limitations.
Amongst those are you cannot use an EXEC function in a UDF.
You'll have to settle for a stored procedure to execute the dynamic SQL.

Some things I have to mention.... or face a downvote ;-)

1) Watch out for SQL injection when using dynamic SQL
2) You should use the quotename function when building dynamic SQL
3) DBAs don't like it when you use dynamic SQL

Give this a try...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnFindsWithNotes
        @table          nvarchar(50), 
        @FindTypeID     int, 
        @qtyfld         nvarchar(50), 
        @wtfld          nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQL = '
SELECT * INTO #temp1
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, @FindTypeID As FindTypeID, ' + @qtyfld + ' AS FindQty, ' + @wtfld + ' AS FindWeight, Notes, NotesToType
,LTRIM(RTRIM((b.splitdata))) AS FindNotes
FROM ' + @table + 
' CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.Notes,''^'') AS b
) AS k

SELECT * INTO #temp2
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ID, SiteCodeID, TrenchID, Context, findsID, BagNo, @FindTypeID As FindTypeID, ' + @qtyfld + ' AS FindQty, ' + @wtfld + ' AS FindWeight, Notes, NotesToType
,LTRIM(RTRIM((c.splitdata))) As FindTypeIDFromNotes
FROM ' + @table + 
' CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(FindsNWW.NotesToType,''^'') AS c
) AS l
INSERT INTO @query ([SiteCodeID], [TrenchID], [Context], [FindsID], [BagNo], [FindTypeID], [FindQty], [FindWeight], [FindNotes])
SELECT #temp1.SiteCodeID, #temp1.TrenchID, #temp1.Context, #temp1.FindsID, #temp1.BagNo, #temp1.FindTypeID, #temp1.FindQty, #temp1.FindWeight, FindNotes
FROM #temp1 JOIN #temp2 on #temp1.ID = #temp2.ID WHERE FindTypeIDFromNotes = @FindTypeID
DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2'


    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FindTypeID  INT', @FindTypeID

END
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments and the suggestion here. I am struggling against a lack of SP and Function knowledge/experience. As the data is for local data processing to create a table of data which will be used at a later date, fortunately the issue of SQL injection doesn't arise as the users of the final visible data will not have any access to the sql directly, just through web access. Regarding the procedure above, I get an error: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure ReturnFindsWithNotes, Line 33`
`'Invalid object name 'ReturnFindsWithNotes'.`

Comment: Sorry, the error was my fault, I had not removed a previous proc. I will work through this and try to understand the principles, thanks.

Comment: Very much appreciated @Spock, I've added working procedure above.